# Remove child objects from two parents in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove parent tags from a list of links that are each inside a `<p>` and `<span>`

```
<p>
  <span>
    <a href="#">One</a>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <span>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

↓

```
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('p').each(function () {
     $(this).html($(this).firstChild);
 });
```

I've tried muliple ways of doing this but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `a` tags will always be inside a single `span` and a single `p` tag you could call `$("a").unwrap().unwrap();`  [You can learn more about `.unwrap()` here](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).  I've included a working example below.

```js
$("a").unwrap().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span>
    <a href="#">One</a>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <span>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact HTML structure of the `a` elements in relation to their parent `p`, you can extract the `a` elements and then `remove()` the `p` completely:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').insertBefore(this);
    $(this).remove();    
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzw3ksgx/)

This has the benefit of working for any level of nested `a` element.